# html code to embed video for different search strings

Tags: javascript, html, css, gsp

How to embed youtube videos into Javascript code?

Suppose Cat, dog, mouse are shown in web interface and when user clicks on cat he should be able to see youtube video of cat.
In this way my data is different not a single concept.

Comment: show where? as a popup? inside browser?

Comment: from where the url of that video comes?

Comment: try this http://lab.abhinayrathore.com/jquery_youtube/ or you prefeer to start from the scratch?

Comment: I dont have the URL, I just have concept like cat or dog. I want to add the search string like https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=${conceptName.c_name}. Where the concept name  is passed by groovy controller code

Comment: I want to add it as popup.